# Modal on bootstrap wont work

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I had some problems with the modal. It wont appear on the screen. The scripts are working and jquery.js is added before bootstrap.js.

```
<!--LINK IN THE NAVBAR-->
 <li><a href="#Login" data-toggle="modal">Login</a></li>

<!-- START OF MODAL -->
 <div class="modal-open modal" id="Login" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
     <p>Login here!</p>
     <p>Don't have a account? <a href="#SignUp">Sign Up!</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div> 
<!--SCRIPT-->
<script src="script/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="script/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It does work: http://www.bootply.com/1aXeVBzOdC#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> <script src="script/bootstrap.js"></script>
> <script src="script/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
> ```

Loading the bootstrap script twice will break the modal functionality. Load it only once.

Comment: [Your code doesn't work](http://jsbin.com/rocila/1/edit?html,output) but if you make my change [then it does work](http://jsbin.com/rocila/2/edit?html,output). If you have additional problems, they aren't shown in the code you provided.

Comment: Is that the only change you made? Because I have been stuck on that part for ages. Cant seem to get it work!

Comment: Yes, it is the only change I made. You can see the code on the other side of the links in my previous comment.